# How to convert dropdown-list to input tag that shows search matching results in HTML & PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp-2.0

I currently have the following code that shows the query results to option tags. But I want to convert it to the input that shows the matching results when the user inputs some words just like google's search input (Combo box?).  How can I make a input, and a script that finds a matching result from the following data($notebook) with the user's inputs? And what make things complicated is that I want to submit the `value='.$n['Note']['member_id']` and not the value the user inputs  if possible, since I'm a beginner there should be a better solution that I dont know. If possible some examples will be great since I wasn't able to find a good solution by googling. I am totally helpless and I really want to love to hear from you!

```
<form action="" method="get">
<select>
    <?php 
    foreach($notebook as $n):?>
   <?php 
     echo '<option name="my" value='.$n['Note']['member_id'].'>'.$n['Note']['member_name'].'</option>'; 
    ?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php unset($notebook); ?>
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a auto-complete kind of thing. Check the below example:

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  

 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" placeholder="type j">
</div>
```

[Autocomplete Reference](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)